# what is required to make cloud based decentrilzed storage?

Tags: blockchain, p2p, decentralized-applications

So I want to make or rather want to learn how to implement decentralised storage. And I did some research on it that I have to developed P2P sharing network, encryption/decryption, data sharding etc.

But I am still confused about how to implement P2P network and how to share files on top of it.

Any links to start on will be appreciated.

Consider I am totally new to this topics.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Questions here are generally required to be more specific, as answering your question conclusively is rather impossible.

Comment: If it's cloud-based I wouldn't really call it decentralized. You would end up relying on a few big providers.

Comment: @the8472 can you give more insight on decentralized storage without Cloud

Comment: this kind of question belongs to https://stackexchange.com
stackoverflow is for specific programming questions, especially coding.